# How spring beans really works

Tags: java, spring

I am new with Spring and I am trying to understand the basic concepts. One important concept from my point of view are spring beans and here I have a problem in fully understand them because resources from the internet are mixing old java code (EJB) with spring annotations and for me is not very clear what is absolutely necessary.

For example, I am trying to understand how autowired works in a basic example like this:

```
@Component("fooFormatter")
class FooFormatter {
public String format() {
    return "foo";
  }
}

class FooService {
@Autowired
private  FooFormatter fooFormatter;

public  void print() {
    System.out.println(fooFormatter.format());
  }
}

 public class App{
 public static void main(String [] args) {
    FooService fo = new FooService();
    fo.print();
   }
 }
```

I have understood that in the main I am creating a new object that is not managed by the spring container but the object type is **FooService** but **FooFormatter** and I don't understand why does not work.
And again if I use spring annotations is necessary to add a file for bean configuration?
I know that is a dummy question and if you know some good resources that explain this in details please leave it here (until now I didn't found some resources to clarify this).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to let Spring inject something in `FooService`, `FooService` should be a manageable bean as well. Otherwise, how would Spring know about it? It basically looks up for classes marked by its annotations. If a class doesn't have, let's say, the `@Component` annotation over it, Spring will not be managing the class.

Annotate the service with

```
@Service
class FooService {
```

create an `ApplicationContext`

```
ApplicationContext context = ...;
```

and request a bean

```
FooService service = context.getBean(FooService.class);
```

Spring isn't a magic tool. `FooService fo = new FooService();` will have no effect on it. A Spring context should be created at some point, it will register classes to manage, and you will be able to inquiry a managed bean.

### To read:

[docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/) is one of the best documentation I've ever read. Read the "Core" section.

Comment: I have seen examples where ApplicationContext was not used. It was market the class wit autowired and simple it works.Just like this guy from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5bkniAjkZA . He just marks the class with autowire and works without creating an ApplicationContext

Comment: @Adrian "simply it works" - nothing in the world simply (read "magically") works. The guy from the video uses `@SpringBootApplication` and calls `SpringApplication.run` which creates a context for him

Comment: now make sense. There are a lot of details in Spring and I am still new with this framework. Thank you for time

Answer (score 0):

Spring bean is simply the backbone of applications and managed by IoC.Like Instantiate assembled and configured .You can use @autowired annotattions for all this.and use both constructore also for loose Coupling.

@Componenet means something to which spring will autodetect.

You can use these  links

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean

https://www.journaldev.com/21429/spring-component

Answer (score 0):

To know more detail. As i did, to know when the Component class is instanciated, make a blank contructor and print some value inside it

```
@Component
public class ComponentClass{
  public ComponentClass(){
    //constructor will be called when autowired
    System.out.println("ComponentClass is instanciated at "+new Date().toString()); 
  }


}
```